# Pandas dataframe - Select row with WildCards

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in python. My question is tucked in a bit. I would like to select row from dataFrame if any string from cells match with specific wildcards rules. Let us assume this example :

**Table to Screen:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Column':[
    'select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparisons against two columns',
    'select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas',
    'use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe',
    'selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on row conditions',
    'select particular columns from inside groups in pandas dataframe']})

  Column
0 select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparisons against two columns
1 select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas
2 use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe
3 selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on row conditions
4 select particular columns from inside groups in pandas dataframe
```

**Rules:**

```
Rules=pd.DataFrame({'SearchTerms':['*select*DataFrame*row*','*select*dataframe*row*']})

  SearchTerms
0 *select*DataFrame*row*
1 *select*dataframe*row*
```

**Results:**

```
  Column
0 select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparisons against two columns
1 select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas
2 use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe
```

I tried to use fnmatch with multiple statements like that:

```
import fnmatch
selection=[]
for row in df['Column']:
   selection.append(fnmatch.fnmatch(row,Rules[0])|fnmatch.fnmatch(row,Rules[1]))
```

**QUESTION**

How  can I select rows from dataFrame with variable number of wildcards statements ?

Life goin' nowhere. Somebody help me!!! ;)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Provide dataframe example?

Comment: Sure @CharlesMorris

Comment: So, you want to search your first dataframe, looking for matches against the two string conditions contained within your rules dataframe? What word within the rules dataframe do you need to search? I.e. is it `DataFrame` or `row` or `rows` or `Dataframe`?  Does your function work?

Comment: My utlimate goal is to search wildcards pattern in first dataframe. Thus, in this example, I would like to extract all rows from `df` which match with `*select*DataFrame*row*` **OR** `*select*dataframe*row*` (number of rules may vary).

Comment: Right, but the search term is not the full string `*select*DataFrame*row*` it is `DataFramerow` ?

Comment: @B.Gees, i don't understand how did you get row with index `2` in the resulting DF... Could you please explain?

Comment: This is an example. With fnmatch we can check if a sentence matches with wildcard `*select*DataFrame*row*`. It is possible to do that in order to select row from dataFrame ?

Comment: @B.Gees, i do understand wildcards differently, so that your DF has only one match: `selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on row conditions`. Do you mean that __all__ words in the `Rules` should be in the row in __any__ order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for "wildcards":

Data:

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]:
                                                                  Column
0  select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparisons against two columns
1     select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas
2            use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe
3      selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on row conditions
4       select particular columns from inside groups in pandas dataframe

In [54]: Rules
Out[54]:
              SearchTerms
0  *select*DataFrame*row*
1  *select*dataframe*row*
```

Solution:

```
In [55]: pat = Rules.SearchTerms.str.replace('\*', r'.*').str.cat(sep='|')

In [56]: df[df.Column.str.contains(pat, flags=re.I)]
Out[56]:
                                                              Column
3  selecting columns from a pandas dataframe based on row conditions
```

Generated RegEx pattern:

```
In [64]: pat
Out[64]: '.*select.*DataFrame.*row.*|.*select.*dataframe.*row.*'
```

Comment: Ok so with pandas dataframe it is necessary to use regex? It is not possible to use statement like : if matches with (`dataframe` **AND** `row` **AND** `select`) **OR** (`DataFrame` **AND** `row` **AND** `select`)

Comment: Please help me to anderstand more about that, I am very interesting in that :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: @B.Gees, give me some time, i'll try to provide you another solution - for [the question from this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42187261/pandas-dataframe-select-row-with-wildcards/42187631#comment71537381_42187631) Do you want to use case-insensitive search?

Comment: Yep exactly. I give you all my intension. Currently I parse multiple databases with python and I search specific information from sentences. All my tables are pandas dataframe and at this stage I need to select sentences if combination words match like  (`dataframe` AND `row` AND `select`) OR (`DataFrame` AND `row` AND `select`). Thus the order of request is not very important. If we use regular expression, I select all sentences with the order `dataframe` AND `row` AND `select` but not `select ` AND `row` AND `dataframe ` for example. thanks a lot MaxU

Comment: @B.Gees, what about case-sensitivity?

Comment: @B.Gees, one more question - how big do you expect the `Rules` DF to be?

Comment: This is variable to depend of the number of rules needed to track my data :/

Comment: @B.Gees, i think the most appropriate solution would be using SOLR, ElasticSearch, etc. - it's their nature to perform such a search

Answer (score 4):

I think you might have better success using the built-in string matching functions in pandas.  If you have a pandas Series object (a DataFrame columns is a Series object) which is a collection of strings, you can call `.str.<method>`.  There is a pretty big collection of string methods available, but in this case, you can use either `.str.match(...)` or `.str.contains(...)`.

Both of these methods accept regular expression statements.  This means changing your wild card expressions to regEx.

```
df[df.Column.str.match('select|DataFrame|row', case=False)]

                                          Column
0  select rows in pandas DataFrame using comparis...
1  select rows from a DataFrame based on values i...
3  selecting columns from a pandas dataframe base...
4  select particular columns from inside groups i...
```

Comment: Hello @James. Fine but in this solution it is not possible to apply **AND** statement ?

Comment: Thanks James for your solution